# Natural Language Processing Models Timeline

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, data-science

I was looking for all the models being developed for NLP since word2vec till now. I was thinking of writing a detailed guide for the **timeline of models in NLP** as an article. Please help me here.
It would be great if answer given will be as:
**Model name**, **year published**, **link to the paper** and **little summary about the model**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a literature review rather than asking a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This repository contains landmark research papers in Natural Language Processing that came out in this century.

Efficient Estimation of Word Representations in Vector Space, Google

Distributed Representations of Words and Phrases, Google

Distributed Representations of Sentences and Documents, Google

Enriching Word Vectors with Subword Information, Facebook

Bag of Tricks for Efficient Text Classification, Facebook

Hierarchical Probabilistic Neural Network Language Model

A Scalable Hierarchical Distributed Language Model

BERT Pre-training of Deep Bidirectional Transformers for Language Understanding, Google

Language Models are Unsupervised Multitask Learners, OpenAI

Wav2Letter, Facebook

Misspelling Oblivious Word Embeddings, Facebook

refer to this repo: https://github.com/Akshat4112/NLP-research-papers